# Why does "x-systemd.growfs" in fstab not work for the rootfs?

Tags: systemd, fstab

I'm running Linux with systemd 249. The /etc/fstab entries are:

```
# cat /etc/fstab
/dev/root            /                    auto       defaults,x-systemd.growfs          1  1
proc                 /proc                proc       defaults                           0  0
devpts               /dev/pts             devpts     mode=0620,ptmxmode=0666,gid=5      0  0
tmpfs                /run                 tmpfs      mode=0755,nodev,nosuid,strictatime 0  0
tmpfs                /var/volatile        tmpfs      defaults                           0  0

/dev/mmcblk2p3       /data                ext4       x-systemd.growfs                   0  0
```

After starting systemd says that the `/data` partition was grown (which is what I expext) but the `/` partition is not even mentioned. Running the `systemd-growfs /` by hand grows the partiton as expected.
What am I missing??

I just discovered an error message related to this problem:
`systemd-growfs[235]: Failed to open "/dev/block/179:1": No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/21592 this seems to be a problem for before 252 versions.

I wrote my own service calling `systemd-growfs /` to work around the problem.